# Get value from xarray format in python

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I try to get data from netCDF format with xarray

I have code like this,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
import sys, json
import base64

ds = xr.open_dataset('/home/misdan/Documents/Data/Angin/wind_1992.nc')
da = ds['u10'].sel(time='1992-02',latitude=6.0, longitude=95.20,method='nearest').data

print('--------------------------')
print('hasilnya adalah : ')
print(da)
```

The result is like this

```
hasilnya adalah : 
[-2.2909293]
```

how i can get the value from the result without [], like this

```
hasilnya adalah : 
-2.2909293
```

the data is like this

```
<xarray.DataArray 'u10' (time: 1)>
array([-2.290929], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
    longitude  float32 95.25
    latitude   float32 6.0
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1992-02-01
Attributes:
    units:      m s**-1
    long_name:  10 metre U wind component
```

Comment: Same way you get data from any other array: `da[0]`

Comment: but i get like this, z = da[0]
IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: What is the output of `type(da)`?

Comment: <xarray.DataArray 'u10' (time: 1)>
array([-2.290929], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
    longitude  float32 95.25
    latitude   float32 6.0
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1992-02-01
Attributes:
    units:      m s**-1
    long_name:  10 metre U wind component

Comment: the data is like this

Comment: i add to my tread

Answer (score 2):

`print(da[0])` will print the first item in the `da` list, which is what you are looking for.